# Run php function in mPDF

Tags: php, function, mpdf

Helllo. I have a problem when try run php function in mPDF html code. For examle:

funtion.php:

```
function write(){echo "123"}
```

mPDF file:

```
$html ='<html>'.write().'</html>';
```

but in pdf file not display "123"

Comment: Change `echo "123"` to `return "123"`

Comment: Replace `function write(){return "123";} echo '<html>'.write().'</html>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function write(){
   $message = "123";
   return $message;
}
```

Use return instead of `echo`. You want to print the output of your function not something that is printed in the function.

- *small note*: in this example `echo` will also work, the error is in your syntax.

You should be getting a `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'`, change your function to:

```
function write(){echo "123";}
```