# Add some data from php function into mpdf

Tags: php, function, mpdf

I have php function, whose create some blocks with data from loop.

finction.php:

```
    function drawcomplect() {

    for ($i=0;$i<count($new_arr);$i++) {

        if ($i%2==0) {
            echo "<div class='numeric'>".$j++."</div>";
            echo "<div class='item'>".$new_arr[$i]."</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='count'>".$new_arr[$i]."</div>";
               }
        }
       }
```

And mPdf file for output:

```
$html ='<html>'.drawcomplect().'</html>'
```

If run this function in php file, it's work. But mPdf not work, print "Page error". How I can add data to pdf?

Comment: Try `return` instead of `echo`

Comment: return break the loop

Comment: @DmitryPHP, concatenate the produced HTML in a new variable within your function and `return` it AFTER the loop.

Comment: btw, not clear `$new_arr` and `$j` are come from if this is the complete body of your function?

Comment: I don’t understand how to concatenate in the loop. Can you help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run php function in mPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946483/run-php-function-in-mpdf)

Answer (score 1):

```
   function drawcomplect() {
      $str = '';

      for ($i=0;$i<count($new_arr);$i++) {

        if ($i%2==0) {
            $str .="<div class='numeric'>".$j++."</div><div class='item'>".$new_arr[$i]."</div>";
        } else {
            $str .="<div class='count'>".$new_arr[$i]."</div>";
        }
      }
      return $str;
   }
```

ANd Mpdf:
`$html ='<html><body>'.drawcomplect().'</body></html>'`

Comment: Declare `$str = '';` at the beginning.